# no data in asp listbox using databinding to database and session variables

Tags: asp.net, session, listbox, data-binding

I was hopeing someone could point out where I am making a mistake. I don't see any data in my list box.

I have a listbox asp control bound to a database and making a comparison to a session field value:

C# code:

```
   singleton Osingleton;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Osingleton = singleton.GetCurrentSingleton();
        Osingleton.Member_Of = "yahoo";
```

html code:

"

```
                SelectCommand="SELECT [Member_Email] FROM [tbl_User] WHERE ([Member_Of] LIKE '%' + @Member_Of + '%')">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:SessionParameter Name="Osingleton" SessionField="Member_Of" 
                        Type="String" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure it out so I used querystring instead.